# strange variable structure I never seen before,

Tags: c#

Can anybody explain this var statement in C#? I can not git this identifier what it meant to be? **(availableItems, preorderItems)**

```
var (availableItems, preorderItems) = await order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync<OrderItemData>(_sort, _products);
```

Comment: See [deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).

Comment: What does `order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync` return?

Comment: It's a new feature in C# 7: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples

Comment: See [C# tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently new syntax. And yes, it is confusing the heck out of me too.

```
var (availableItems, preorderItems) = await order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync<OrderItemData>(_sort, _products);
```

This declares two variables - `var availableItems` and `var preorderItems`.

`order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync<OrderItemData>(_sort, _products);` apparently returns two values in a tuple. But it is annoying to work with tuples directly. So instead, the assignment splits the values of that tuple over those two variables.

According to Dmitry's link, you "deconstruct" the tuple that `order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync<OrderItemData>(_sort, _products);` returns, splitting it into two normal variables that you can easily work with.

I guess a equivalent would be:

```
var temp = await order.GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync<OrderItemData>(_sort, _products);
var availableItems = temp.Item1;
var preorderItems = temp.Item2;
```

Item1, Item2 and the like are always valid to adress the specific fields of a tuple in order of declaration. Naming fields for tuples was actually a later addition - and is entirely optional to use.

Comment: This is deconstruction, and it's perfectly valid. See @Dmitry's link in the comments: it's a shorthand for unpacking the tuple returned by `GetDifferentiatedProductDataAsync` into two local variables

Comment: @canton7 Ah, now I understand it.